# Color picker with alpha using dat.gui (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, dat.gui

Is there any way to get a color picker which modified the alpha channel of a RGBA color using dat.gui ( http://code.google.com/p/dat-gui/ )?

Currently I'm only able to change the RGB value using the color picker - even though the color picker accepts an alpha value.

Example (also available http://jsfiddle.net/mortennobel/PT3g2/1/ ):

```
var ColorObject = function() {
   this.color = [ 0, 128, 255, 0.3 ]; // RGB with alpha
    this.showAlert = function(){
        alert("Color is "+this.color);
    } 
};

var colorObject = new ColorObject();
var gui = new dat.GUI();

gui.addColor(colorObject, 'color');
gui.add(colorObject, 'showAlert');
```

Comment: It's working for me. What's the required result that you don't get ?

Comment: I want a slider, so I can change the alpha value in the color picker.

Comment: That functionality is just not available on dat.GUI, so I don't see any answer you are looking for here

Comment: Well dat.GUI is fairly modular and extendable. It must be possible to add this functionality to the color picker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's any easy way to extend existing library. I've just made changes to library itself. You can try it here: http://jsbin.com/anewaz/2

Modified sources are also on my github: https://github.com/mariozski/datGUIwithAlpha/blob/master/dat.gui.js

Hope it'll help :-)

mz